# Word wrap in supertabular two column table entry

Tags: tables, line-breaking, columns, wrap, supertabular

From a [Freeman CV Template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/freeman-cv):

With a two column table defined as following:

```
\begin{supertabular}{rl} % Start a table with two columns, the table will ensure everything is aligned

%------------------------------------------------

\tableentry{Beginner}{Java, MS DOS}{spaceafter}

%------------------------------------------------

\tableentry{Intermediate}{Javascript, Python, HTML, CSS,}{}
\tableentry{}{Microsoft Windows}{}
\tableentry{}{Computer Hardware \& Support}{spaceafter}

%------------------------------------------------

\tableentry{Expert}{Perl, Unix, \LaTeX}{spaceafter}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{supertabular}
```

and `tableentry` command defined as

```
\newcommand{\tableentry}[3]{
    \textsc{#1} & #2\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#3}{}{\\}{\\[6pt]}
}
```

I'm trying to add more text to a `tableentry`, just for example, the text from the frist paragraph in template:

```
\tableentry{Beginner}{My research examined the use of ELW pulses from a mode-locked source array inducted through transuranic crystals to observe entanglement on supraquantum structures. Theoretical advancements included prediction of quantum resonance phenomena including the possibility of resonance cascades. I was motivated to conduct this doctoral research due to my passion for teleportation of matter and I believe I have laid the foundation for further experimental validation and development of practical outcomes.
}{spaceafter}
```

This, however, does not allow any sensible word wrap and unless one uses small sentence in the bullet point, text goes off the page: [image: cropped overflow]

### QUESTION:

How can I achive an entry with sensible word wrap with spacing in-between lines smaller than of those in-between of separate `tableentry`s (or at least sensible word wrap without checking for width overflow each time recompiling)?

Comment: A `l` type column, such as the one you used in `\begin{supertabular}{rl}` is always as wide as its widest entry. As such, the output you observe is exactly the expected one. If you want automatic linebreaks, use a `p` type column of appropriate width instead.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to align text left or right inside a `p` column? If yes, how? @leandriis

Comment: Sure, you can use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{<width>}` and `>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{<width>}` respectively.